# Select several checkboxes in the same group

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a set of checkboxes, where I can only check one box per group, how do I change so I can check multiple boxes per group?

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dNwqzx

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".filterGenius input").each(function() {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf($(this).val()) >= 0) {
      $(this).attr("checked", "checked")
    }
  });
  $(".filterGenius select option").each(function() {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf($(this).val()) >= 0) {
      $(this).attr('selected', true);
    }
  });

  $(".filterGenius input").change(function() {

    var s = encodeURI(unescape(jQuery.query.set("fss", getFSS())));
    var o = window.location.href.split("?")[0];

    $(".filterGenius input").attr("disabled", true);

    window.location.href = o + s
  });
});

$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
  $('input[name="' + this.name + '"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

```html
<div class="filterGenius">
  <div class="col">
    <b>Manufacturer</b>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Manufacturer" value="HP" /> <span class "filtertext">HP</span>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Manufacturer" value="Dell" /> <span class "filtertext">Dell</span>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Manufacturer" value="Lenovo" /> <span class "filtertext">Lenovo</span>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Manufacturer" value="Apple" /> <span class "filtertext"> Apple</span>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Manufacturer" value="Acer" /> <span class "filtertext">Acer</span>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Manufacturer" value="Asus" /> <span class "filtertext"> Asus</span>
    <br>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <b>OS</b>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="OS" value="W7H" /> <span class "filtertext">W7H</span>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="OS" value="Bing" /> <span class "filtertext">Bing</span>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="OS" value="W7P" /> <span class "filtertext">W7P</span>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="OS" value="W8P" /> <span class "filtertext">W8P</span>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="OS" value="W8.1P" /> <span class "filtertext">W8.1P</span>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="OS" value="Freedos" /> <span class "filtertext">Freedos</span>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="OS" value="CMAR" /><span class "filtertext"> CMAR</span>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="OS" value="COA" /><span class "filtertext"> COA</span>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last jquery function prevents you from checking multiple boxes. From what I can tell that's all it does. Remove it and you should be able to check as many boxes as you like!

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(".filterGenius input").each(function () {
 if (window.location.href.indexOf($(this).val()) >= 0) {
 $(this).attr("checked", "checked")
}
});

$(".filterGenius select option").each(function () {
if (window.location.href.indexOf($(this).val()) >= 0) {
$(this).attr('selected', true);
}
});

$(".filterGenius input").change(function () { 
var s = encodeURI(unescape(jQuery.query.set("fss", getFSS())));
var o = window.location.href.split("?")[0];

$(".filterGenius input").attr("disabled", true);
window.location.href = o + s
});
});

//$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
//$('input[name="' + this.name + '"]').not(this).prop('checked', //false);
//});
```

```html
<div class="filterGenius">
 <div class="col">
     <b>Manufacturer</b><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Manufacturer_1" value="HP"  /> <span class"filtertext">HP</span><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Manufacturer_2" value="Dell" />  <span class"filtertext">Dell</span><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Manufacturer_3" value="Lenovo" />  <span class"filtertext">Lenovo</span><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Manufacturer_4" value="Apple" /> <span class"filtertext"> Apple</span><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Manufacturer_5" value="Acer" />  <span class"filtertext">Acer</span><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Manufacturer_6" value="Asus" /> <span class"filtertext"> Asus</span><br>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
     <b>OS</b><br>
       <input type="checkbox" name="OS_1" value="W7H"  /> <span class"filtertext">W7H</span><br>
       <input type="checkbox" name="OS_2" value="Bing"  /> <span class"filtertext">Bing</span><br>
       <input type="checkbox" name="OS_3" value="W7P"  /> <span class"filtertext">W7P</span><br>
       <input type="checkbox" name="OS_4" value="W8P"  /> <span class"filtertext">W8P</span><br>
       <input type="checkbox" name="OS_5" value="W8.1P"  /> <span class"filtertext">W8.1P</span><br>
       <input type="checkbox" name="OS_6" value="Freedos"  /> <span class"filtertext">Freedos</span><br>
       <input type="checkbox" name="OS_7" value="CMAR"  /><span class"filtertext"> CMAR</span><br>
       <input type="checkbox" name="OS_8" value="COA"  /><span class"filtertext"> COA</span><br>
   </div>
 </div>
```

This should (hopefully) achieve what you are setting out to do - as @Yunus Saha pointed out

Comment: It does let me check more boxes, but it it will only add the value of the first checked checkbox, not any other that I check.

Comment: So, you would like to have each checked box's value added to where exactly?

Comment: It adds the value to the url - like this: /Workstations?fss=HP and for each group of added checkbox it ads the value with a + = /Workstations?fss=HP+WH7

Comment: Also - I'm guessing there is another chunk of code you have left out but jQuery.query seems to be undefined.in your example.

Comment: yeah it is - I though the code posted would be enough, seems it wasnt that easy. added the full chunck on the codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dNwqzx

Comment: Okay, so, for example you would like the user to be able to select ?fss=HP+Apple+Dell+W7H+Bing etc...? Or just one from manufacturer and one from OS?

Comment: No the first you wrote. today it works with one from each group already, but i want it to work as your second statement, "?fss=HP+Apple+Dell+W7H+Bing etc" - the value from any checkbox.

Comment: Okay, the edited answer should work copy and pasted. Give it a shot.

Comment: No, still the same result. It adds the first value, and lets me check more boxes but only add the first value. Edit: sorry, I missed that you changed the  hmtl.. Will give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

just comment or delete thise lines:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    $('input[name="' + this.name + '"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

Comment: It does let me check more boxes, but it it will only add the value of the first checked checkbox, not any other that I check.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need value of the each checked checkbox so better

Change the name attribute to be unique for each checkbox or use it as an array.

example of Manufacturer checkbox:

`<input type="checkbox" name="Manufacturer[]" value="HP"  />`

do the same for other checkboxes too.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this lines from the javascript codes (last three rows)

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    $('input[name="' + this.name + '"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```